# How to compare integer value in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Hi i'm trying to compare two integer values in jstl it is returning the result false even if the statement is true.

here is my code

```
 String numofcell=(String)request.getAttribute("numberofcell"); 
 int noc = Integer.parseInt(numofcell);
int num = 4;

<c:choose>
    <c:when test = "${noc eq num}">
        <%=noc%>
        hiiiiiiiiiiiii
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <%=noc%>
        HELLLOOOOOOO 
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

output is : 4 HELLLOOOOOOO

Answer (score 1):

You missed EL symbol `${}`, Try,

```
 <c:set var="noc" value="<%=noc%>"/>     
  <c:set var="num" value="<%=num%>"/>


   .....
   <c:when test = "${noc eq num}">
   .........
```

Comment: thanx masud i forget to set variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String numofcell="4";
 int noc = Integer.parseInt(numofcell);
int num = 4;

<c:choose>
    <c:when test = "noc eq num">
        <%=noc%>
        hiiiiiiiiiiiii
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <%=noc%>
        HELLLOOOOOOO 
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

This code giving output : 4 hiiiiiiiiiiiii  4 HELLLOOOOOOO

Answer (score 0):

```
String numofcell="4";
 int noc = Integer.parseInt(numofcell);
int num = 4;
pageContext.setAttribute("noc",noc);
pageContext.setAttribute("num",num);

<c:choose>
    <c:when test = "${noc eq num}">
        <%=noc%>
        hiiiiiiiiiiiii
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <%=noc%>
        HELLLOOOOOOO 
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```